# How to convert Custom Set controller into an extension of standard set controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to convert my Custom controller into an extension so I can embed my VF page into a button on the account search layout. How would I go about doing this?

```
public class CustomAccountListController {
 public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        if(setCon == null) {
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [Select Id, Name, AV_Description__c, BillingCity, BillingState, AV_Points__c, Growth_Indicators__c, Capital_Raised__c, NumberOfEmployees, AV_Founded__c, Status__c, Deal_Lead__c, Outreach_Email_Count__c, Most_Recent_Outreach_Date__c FROM Account WHERE Status__c = 'Lead-New' ORDER BY AV_Points__c Desc]));
        }
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}

// Initialize setCon and return a list of records
public List<Account> getAccounts() {
    return (List<Account>) setCon.getRecords();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor:

```
public CustomAccountListController(ApexPages.StandardSetController ctrl) {
    setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
            [Select Id, Name, AV_Description__c, BillingCity, BillingState, AV_Points__c, 
                    Growth_Indicators__c, Capital_Raised__c, NumberOfEmployees, 
                    AV_Founded__c, Status__c, Deal_Lead__c, Outreach_Email_Count__c, 
                    Most_Recent_Outreach_Date__c 
             FROM Account
             WHERE Status__c = 'Lead-New' 
             ORDER BY AV_Points__c Desc]));
}
```

Change your setCon to a standard get/set model:

```
  public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon { get; set; }
```

You'll need to change the VF page accordingly:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="unused" extensions="CustomAccountListController">
```

Comment: I did this but now where does my Query go so I can specify what is returned? That originally resided in the SetCon method.    `public class CustomAccountListController {
   
   public CustomAccountListController(ApexPages.StandardSetController ctrl) {
    setCon = ctrl;
  }  
    
 public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon { get; set; }

    // Initialize setCon and return a list of records
    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return (List<Account>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
}`

Comment: @Trace Actually, you can set it in the constructor instead of using the parameter passed in to the constructor. I'll edit.

Comment: That worked thanks! One issue though is it only is allowing me to add to the search layout as a list button and not a detail page button. Maybe that is out of the realm of these questions but do you know why that would be?

Comment: @Trace standardSetController allows for list buttons, standardController for detail buttons. If you want both, you'd have to create two different pages. I've done this with a common Visualforce component to reduce the amount of code I have to share.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out! Thanks @sfdcfox you're by far one of the most helpful people on this platform!

Comment: @Trace You're welcome!